# How can i convert json string to java object in android?

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to convert the response from server which is a JSON string,I want to convert that JSONstring to java object.I am trying Gson.Please someone explain and tell me the steps how to do it using Gson.

```
  @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == mLoginButton) {
                LoginUser();

            }
            if (v==mSignUpBtn){
                Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegistrationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        private void LoginUser() {
            // final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
            final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();



            StringRequest postStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,LOGIN_API,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.d(TAG,"Reponse Check :"+response);
                           // Gson gson = new Gson();
                           // String jsonInString = "{}";
                            //LoginActivity staff = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, LoginActivity.class);
                            //Log.d(TAG,"Reponse Check staff :"+staff);

                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e(TAG,"Error Response Check :"+error);
                        }
                    }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    Log.d(TAG,"For email :"+email);
                    Log.d(TAG,"For password :"+password);
                    //try {
                        Log.d(TAG,"My Credentials email URL Encoder: "+( mEncryption.AESEncode(email)));
                        Log.d(TAG,"My Credentials email URL DECODED: "+( mEncryption.AESDecode(mEncryption.AESEncode(email))));

                        params.put("data[User][email]",(mEncryption.AESEncode(email)));

                        Log.d(TAG,"My Credentials pass URL Encoder: "+( mEncryption.AESEncode(password)));
                        paa
                }
```

logcat

```
03-16 16:36:08.346 2618-3428/com.example.user.myapplication D/Null: For email :abc@gmail.com
03-16 16:36:08.346 2618-3428/com.example.user.myapplication D/Null: For password :12345678
03-16 16:36:08.354 2618-3428/com.example.user.myapplication D/Null: My Credentials email URL Encoder: RyUMRBg7UyeIlFBBtNemZFuG46PJtAIdiZWXnlJ4zNI=
03-16 16:36:08.358 2618-3428/com.example.user.myapplication D/Null: My Credentials email URL DECODED: abc@gmail.com
03-16 16:36:08.360 2618-3428/com.example.user.myapplication D/Null: My Credentials pass URL Encoder: pfrt1fKLkoZhAT6hoMJFiA==
03-16 16:36:08.361 2618-3428/com.example.user.myapplication D/Null: Params :{data[User][password]=pfrt1fKLkoZhAT6hoMJFiA==
                                                                    , data[User][email]=RyUMRBg7UyeIlFBBtNemZFuG46PJtAIdiZWXnlJ4zNI=
                                                                    }
03-16 16:36:08.505 2618-2618/com.example.user.myapplication D/Null: Reponse Check :{"code":200,"user":{"User":{"id":"ui1bJkK19jxbaquTboA2oQ==","email":"RyUMRBg7UyeIlFBBtNemZFuG46PJtAIdiZWXnlJ4zNI=","status":"1","verified":"1","created":"2016-03-07 11:41:59","modified":"2016-04-07 15:43:43","token":"6b987332b77d7c69d76bf7be80a85177fb7fa08d"},"Profile":{"id":"1","first_name":"abc","last_name":"fgh","bio":"sfafaf","address":"82, Debinibash Road\r\nDum Dum, P.O. - Motijheel","phone":"+913325505055","profile_pic":"\/img\/356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab\/license.jpg","user_id":"1","Contributor":{"id":"31","profile_id":"1","status":"1","vs_cdn_id":"261961777","secret_token":"s-7Va5z","uploaded_on":null,"statement":"AOK KJDHKJDH bkgkg kkhkjh kjhkj kjh kjhkjh","time":"7 hours per month","created":"2016-05-02 18:40:11","modified":"2016-05-02 18:41:29"},"Moderator":[]},"redirect":"\/"}}
```

Comment: You can found a good tutorial about Gson here http://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/google-gson-tutorial-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Answer (score 0):

You can use in a generic way like:

```
private final static Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().create();

public static <T> T fromJSON(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        return GSON.fromJson(json, clazz);
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        LOGGER.warn("Could not deserialize object", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make activity/fragment from json.

In your onResponse() method:

```
ModelObject obj = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, ModelObject.class);
```

And make ModelObject class something like this:

```
public class ModelObject {
int field1;
int field2;
//here you should make getters and setters;
}
```

After it you can do anything you need with this object (pass it to any activity or fragment).

Comment: could you please give more hint on ModelObject class??and also about getter setter.

Comment: you've already made model class (User_) and getters and setters (look at methods that starts with get*** and set***), now - just replace ModelObject everywhere with User

Answer (score 0):

Gson will map the values to the corresponding model class object if the fields are given correctly. Have a look at the below model classes. After that, if you call `Example data = GSON.fromJson(yourJson, Example.class);` ,  this data object will have all that you need.

-----------------------------------com.example.Contributor.java-----------------------------------

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Contributor {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("profile_id")
@Expose
private String profileId;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("vs_cdn_id")
@Expose
private String vsCdnId;
@SerializedName("secret_token")
@Expose
private String secretToken;
@SerializedName("uploaded_on")
@Expose
private Object uploadedOn;
@SerializedName("statement")
@Expose
private String statement;
@SerializedName("time")
@Expose
private String time;
@SerializedName("created")
@Expose
private String created;
@SerializedName("modified")
@Expose
private String modified;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getProfileId() {
return profileId;
}

public void setProfileId(String profileId) {
this.profileId = profileId;
}

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

public String getVsCdnId() {
return vsCdnId;
}

public void setVsCdnId(String vsCdnId) {
this.vsCdnId = vsCdnId;
}

public String getSecretToken() {
return secretToken;
}

public void setSecretToken(String secretToken) {
this.secretToken = secretToken;
}

public Object getUploadedOn() {
return uploadedOn;
}

public void setUploadedOn(Object uploadedOn) {
this.uploadedOn = uploadedOn;
}

public String getStatement() {
return statement;
}

public void setStatement(String statement) {
this.statement = statement;
}

public String getTime() {
return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
this.time = time;
}

public String getCreated() {
return created;
}

public void setCreated(String created) {
this.created = created;
}

public String getModified() {
return modified;
}

public void setModified(String modified) {
this.modified = modified;
}

}
```

-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private Integer code;
@SerializedName("user")
@Expose
private User user;

public Integer getCode() {
return code;
}

public void setCode(Integer code) {
this.code = code;
}

public User getUser() {
return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
this.user = user;
}

}
```

-----------------------------------com.example.Profile.java-----------------------------------

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Profile {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("first_name")
@Expose
private String firstName;
@SerializedName("last_name")
@Expose
private String lastName;
@SerializedName("bio")
@Expose
private String bio;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private String address;
@SerializedName("phone")
@Expose
private String phone;
@SerializedName("profile_pic")
@Expose
private String profilePic;
@SerializedName("user_id")
@Expose
private String userId;
@SerializedName("Contributor")
@Expose
private Contributor contributor;
@SerializedName("Moderator")
@Expose
private List<Object> moderator = null;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getBio() {
return bio;
}

public void setBio(String bio) {
this.bio = bio;
}

public String getAddress() {
return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
this.address = address;
}

public String getPhone() {
return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
this.phone = phone;
}

public String getProfilePic() {
return profilePic;
}

public void setProfilePic(String profilePic) {
this.profilePic = profilePic;
}

public String getUserId() {
return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
this.userId = userId;
}

public Contributor getContributor() {
return contributor;
}

public void setContributor(Contributor contributor) {
this.contributor = contributor;
}

public List<Object> getModerator() {
return moderator;
}

public void setModerator(List<Object> moderator) {
this.moderator = moderator;
}

}
```

-----------------------------------com.example.User.java-----------------------------------

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class User {

@SerializedName("User")
@Expose
private User_ user;
@SerializedName("Profile")
@Expose
private Profile profile;
@SerializedName("redirect")
@Expose
private String redirect;

public User_ getUser() {
return user;
}

public void setUser(User_ user) {
this.user = user;
}

public Profile getProfile() {
return profile;
}

public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
this.profile = profile;
}

public String getRedirect() {
return redirect;
}

public void setRedirect(String redirect) {
this.redirect = redirect;
}

}
```

-----------------------------------com.example.User_.java-----------------------------------

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class User_ {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("verified")
@Expose
private String verified;
@SerializedName("created")
@Expose
private String created;
@SerializedName("modified")
@Expose
private String modified;
@SerializedName("token")
@Expose
private String token;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getEmail() {
return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

public String getVerified() {
return verified;
}

public void setVerified(String verified) {
this.verified = verified;
}

public String getCreated() {
return created;
}

public void setCreated(String created) {
this.created = created;
}

public String getModified() {
return modified;
}

public void setModified(String modified) {
this.modified = modified;
}

public String getToken() {
return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
this.token = token;
}

}
```